# Am I using static_cast correctly?

Tags: c++

I'm converting a string into an array of char.

I've tried static_cast to do this and I'm somewhat new to programming. I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly.

```
string Password::encrypt(string p_user){
pass = p_user;
char word[pass.length()];
for(int i = 0; i < pass.length(); i++){
    word[i] = static_cast<char>(pass.substr(i, i+1)); // Every letter in one index
}

return "";
}
```

The error is as follows: "Cannot convert 'std::_cx11::basic_string

Comment: A string is already an array of characters. Do you specifically need it to be an independent array of characters?

Comment: That `for` loop boils down to `std::copy(pass.begin(), pass.end(), word);`. Why are you copying the string?

Comment: @NicolBolas yes. I need to to this conversion.
ascii value of encrypted char =  ((ascii value of plain char - 33) + 25) % 94 + 33

Comment: Why? What will it be used for? The signature `string Password::encrypt(string p_user)` implies that you are going to return a string eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `substr` method of `std::string` class returns `std::string`, that cannot be converted to char through `static_cast`. Let me provide a work around for this problem:

```
char word[pass.length()];
for(int i = 0; i < pass.length(); i++){
    word[i] = static_cast<char>(pass.substr(i, i+1)[0]); // Here as it is a length of 1, we can access with index 0, which will give a char
}
```

Infact there is no need of `static_cast` also, you can simply write as follows:

```
char word[pass.length()];
for(int i = 0; i < pass.length(); i++){
    word[i] = pass[i];
}
```

Hope this helps, thanks,

Rajkumar

Comment: This worked! Thank you! I didn't know a string was an array of chars.

Comment: @daman540 "_I didn't know a string was an array of chars_" - With this newfound knowledge - do you still think you really _need_ to create a raw `char[]`? And `char word[pass.length()];` (a `VLA`) will rarely be received well since it's a non-standard extension.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in the standard library that support casting a `std::string` to a `char`. Hence, `static_cast<char>(pass.substr(i, i+1))` is an invalid expression. It's not clear to me why you are using that instead of the much more straight forward:

```
word[i] = pass[i];
```

#### Additionally ...

Use of

```
char word[pass.length()];
```

is non-standard. Some compilers support it as an extension. Use `std::vector<char>` instead.

```
std::vector<char> word(pass.length());
```

Comment: We haven't learned vector format yet. I know how to, but my professor won't allow it.

Comment: @daman540, in that, it will be better to use a dynamically allocated array instead of using a non-standard mechanism. `char* word = new char[pass.length()];`